# Sort array elements based on the value of array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a following array of objects:

```
[
  0: {
    id: 1,
    type: 'input'   
  },
  1: {
    id: 2,
    type: 'boolean'   
  },
  2: {
    id: 3,
    type: 'choice'   
  },
  3: {
    id: 1,
    type: 'select'   
  },
]
```

I want to sort the array element based on the value of type. If type is 'choice' I want to place the element in the last place of array i.e. 4th place. If type is 'boolean', place it in third place. If type is 'select', place it in second place.

I know how to sort an array with numerical values.

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.type < b.type) return -1
  return a.type > b.type ? 1 : 0
})
```

I am having problem comparing property values and sorting it.

Please help me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Consider a separate array that holds types in their desired order, and sort based on their index in that array. Or a hashmap that has type and position.

Comment: Um, there is no `name` property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if need to sort an array based on some string property of object you need to create another which represents the order of sort. Then use `indexOf` and subtract the indexes

```js
const order = ['input', 'select', 'boolean','choice'];

const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'input'   
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'boolean'   
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 'choice'   
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'select'   
  },
]

arr.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a.type) - order.indexOf(b.type));
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'input',
    val: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'boolean',
    val: 3
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 'choice',
    val: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'select',
    val: 2
  },
]
```

then it would be easy: just `arr.sort((a, b) => a.val - b.val)`

Since you don't have the property `val`, you can just set it on before:

```
const typeToValue = {
  input: 1,
  boolean: 3,
  choice: 4,
  select: 2
}
arr.forEach(el => {
  el.val = typeToValue[el.type]
})
arr.sort((a, b) => a.val - b.val)
```

Maybe you don't want to dirty your elements, notice that `el.val == typeToValue[el.type]`

Meaning you can write
`arr.sort((a, b)=>typeToValue[a.type] - typeToValue[b.type])`

Finally should you have a sorted array `['input', 'select', 'boolean', 'choice']` you can trivially transform it to `typeToValue` object via `Array.prototype.reduce`

```
const orders = ['input', 'select', 'boolean', 'choice']
const typeToValue = orders.reduce((o, el, i) => (o[el] = i, o), {})
```

or if you don't like reduce with `Object.fromEntries`

```
const typeToValue = Object.fromEntries(orders.map((el, i) => [el, i]))
```

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"type":"input"},{"id":2,"type":"boolean"},{"id":3,"type":"choice"},{"id":1,"type":"select"}]
const orders = ['input', 'select', 'boolean', 'choice']
const typeToValue1 = orders.reduce((o, el, i) => (o[el] = i, o), {})
const typeToValue2 = Object.fromEntries(orders.map((el, i) => [el, i]))

// just slice to copy array because sort modify in place
console.log(arr.slice(0).sort((a, b)=>typeToValue1[a.type] - typeToValue1[b.type]))
console.log(arr.slice(0).sort((a, b)=>typeToValue2[a.type] - typeToValue2[b.type]))
```

Comment: Thank You for the detailed answer. :)

Comment: you are welcome @SujanShrestha :)